# Installing psycopg2 in an alpine docker container

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to get my django application to use PostgreSQL, however, so far no luck. I set the application to use the PostgreSQL database and linked both containers using `docker-compose.yml`, but I am getting the error that the module psycopg2 is missing. I installed all of the dependencies as follow: `apk --update add python3-dev, postgresql-client, postgresql-dev, musl-dev` and when I try to install psycopg2 using pip `pip3 install psycopg2` I get the following error:

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.6.2.tar.gz (376kB)
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6.2 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090409 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-6wmwilb_/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-f8ye_ro8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2

copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2

copying lib/psycopg1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2

copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2

copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2

copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2

copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2

copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2

copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2

copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_notify.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_lobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_errcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/dbapi20_tpc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_types_basic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_dates.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_bugX000.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_copy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_async.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/testutils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_cancel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_quote.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_with.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/testconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_transaction.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_green.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_types_extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_cursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_bug_gc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

copying tests/test_extras_dictcursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests

Skipping implicit fixer: buffer

Skipping implicit fixer: idioms

Skipping implicit fixer: set_literal

Skipping implicit fixer: ws_comma

running build_ext

building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg

gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6.2 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090409 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-6wmwilb_/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-f8ye_ro8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-6wmwilb_/psycopg2
```

Am I missing a dependency or am I installing psycopg2 wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that `gcc` compiler is missing completely? I've just tried it with the latest alpine image and `apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev && pip3 install psycopg2` works.

Answer (score 11):

Add this in the Dockerfile of your django app

```
RUN apk add build-base
```

It is like build-essentials, include basic build tools for compiling C/C++
programs